# Tetrahedron Die Question

Tags: probability

A uniform unbiased die is constructed in the shape of a regular tetrahedron with faces numbered 2, 2, 3 and 4 and the score is taken from the face on which the die lands. If two such dice are thrown together, find the probability of scoring:

(i) exactly 6 on each of 3 successive throws.

(ii) more than 4 on at least one of the three successive throws.

The answers are (i) $\frac{125}{16^{3}}$ (ii) $\frac{63}{64}$

To get six we have the following condition (2,4),(4,2)&(3,3). Total number of cases are 2+2+1=5 for first throw, now regarding this die where we have same number, there are nine cases not 16: (2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4), so the answer should be $\frac{5^{3}}{9^{3}}$.

Please help me with the answer, I have not proceeded onto (ii) as (i) is not matching.

Comment: I have not faced any problem even on cuboid die where six face die has two same number

Comment: You have correctly counted two possibilities of landing on a $2$. However, although there are only three numerical outcomes for each of the dice, there are four faces - so you need to count four possibilities. The chance of landing on a $2$ is twice the chance of a $3$ or a $4$. Counting only three possibilities treats them as if they are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're doing in the first task is that you divide by $9$ instead of $16$. There are $16$ equally probable outcomes out of which $5$ would produce a score of $5$ which means that the probability of scoring a $6$ would be $5/16$ doing that three times means cubing it giving $5^3/16^3 = 125/4096$.

The second is the complementary event of scoring $4$ on three throws. There are $4$ ways to score a $4$ out of $16$ which means that probability is $4/16=1/4$ doing that thrice means cubing the probability which would be $1/4^3=1/64$. The complementary event would be $1-1/64=63/64$.

Comment: I missed this step, thanks for prompt reply